# missing ; before statement node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have this code which i can't find the error where it indicates missing ; before statement

```
"dimelo_source": {
"api_identifier": "e2fb3xxxxxxxx5c1f74425b3",
"source_id": "5e906bxxxxxxxx8abfe75421",
"access_token": "a90d550c0exxxxxxxx3587a8b161a8ac4b51f7ee8ac34f6563e533293d153368"
}
"routing": {
"timeout": 1800
},
"webhook_events": {
"intervention.closed": "[routing:{\"type\":\"managed\",\"destination\":\"smartlyai\"}][message:{\"type\":\"message\",\"content\":{\"type\":\"postback\",\"value\":\"handover_end\"}}]"
},
"options": {
"traffic_type": "MESSAGE_TAG",
"tag": "POST_PURCHASE_UPDATE"
}
callback(output);
```

Comment: Please post the complete code

Comment: this suppose to be inside an abject , btw u missed ,(comma) after first object

Comment: @shubh what's missing? i just have this code and i must find the error

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is going to solve your problem, but it seems to me that after `access_token` is missing a comma (`,`)

Comment: We need more context. With the code you shared, is impossible to find the error. 

Maybe you could add a `;` before the `callback` function? I don't see why it should error, but it's worth a try.

Comment: from what language  this code was built i have no idea ?

Answer (score 0):

the original object should be like this

```
{
   "dimelo_source":{
      "api_identifier":"e2fb3xxxxxxxx5c1f74425b3",
      "source_id":"5e906bxxxxxxxx8abfe75421",
      "access_token":"a90d550c0exxxxxxxx3587a8b161a8ac4b51f7ee8ac34f6563e533293d153368"
   },
   "routing":{
      "timeout":1800
   },
   "webhook_events":{
      "intervention.closed":"[routing:{\"type\":\"managed\",\"destination\":\"smartlyai\"}][message:{\"type\":\"message\",\"content\":{\"type\":\"postback\",\"value\":\"handover_end\"}}]"
   },
   "options":{
      "traffic_type":"MESSAGE_TAG",
      "tag":"POST_PURCHASE_UPDATE"
   }
}
```